# How to set Wildfly/JBoss domain controller IP address in managed servers using CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to change the domain controller IP address in JBoss/Wildfly managed servers using the management cli, but the configuration either keeps unchanged or changes in the wrong way.

I can find the domain controller settings in /opt/wildfly/domain/configuration/host-slave.xml:

```
<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.0">
    <domain-controller>
        <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <discovery-options>
                <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"/>
            </discovery-options>
        </remote>
    </domain-controller>
</host>
```

And these were my failed attempts so far:

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -Djboss.domain.master.address=192.168.57.13
embed-host-controller --host-config=host-slave.xml
set host=`:read-children-names(child-type=host)`

/host=$host/core-service=discovery-options/static-discovery=primary:write-attribute(name=host,value="${jboss.domain.master.address:192.168.57.13}")
/host=$host:write-remote-domain-controller(host=192.168.57.13,port=9999,security-realm=ManagementRealm)
/host=$host:write-remote-domain-controller(host=192.168.57.13, security-realm=ManagementRealm)
/host=$host:write-remote-domain-controller(host=remote,security-realm=ManagementRealm)
```

After restarting Wildfly, I get errors like this, making it clear the managed server still doesn't know about the managed domain IP:

```
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("host" => "gerenciado-centos-7"),
    ("core-service" => "discovery-options"),
    ("static-discovery" => "primary")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${jboss.domain.master.address}'"
```

The setting I expect to change is `host="${jboss.domain.master.address}"`, but it just doesn't.

This is one of my managed servers info:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

JAVA_HOME=/usr /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -v
...
WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final)
```

Which is the right syntax to point my managed servers to the correct domain controller?

> Why don't I just edit the file? Because I need to automate the thing, and I understand the Management CLI is the way to get it done safely.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Both CentOS and WildFly are end of life

Comment: @RomeoNinov Good point. Could you pls share EOL references for both? I'd like to warn those who bring me such automation tasks...

Comment: My mistake, Centos 7 will be EOL middle of next year: https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/centos-linux-eol About WildFly 10: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279838 (not formal support for product)

Comment: @RomeoNinov That was it! I did exactly the same in Wildfly 30, over Rocky Linux 9, and it worked. As far as I could understand from the docs, this is valid syntax for Wildfly 10 too, so I probably hit a bug already solved between versions. I have still to demonstrate that and find first working version, but this is another thing. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it, but please don't edit the solution into your question. Instead, post it as answer or ask whomever helped you to post an answer. Either way, accept an answer, otherwise the question will stay as unsolved in the system forever.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You're right. I'll do that.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, could you pls repost the EOL info for my initial testbed - CentOS 7 and Wildfly 10 - as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First CentOS 7 is almost EOL which is not wise for corporate system. Will be good to switch to other RH clone (like Rocky Linux 9, see OP comment). Also you can consider subscribe to RedHat Linux and get all the benefits for support, and long term life.

But more important the version of WildFly is problematic. This is quite old version which is without any support. So even if you find a bug (which can be the case) you will get no update of the software. Better migrate the software to new version (which OP did, switching to Wildfly 30).

*In short*: CentOS 7 + Wildfly 10 have integration problems, reported (in comment) Wildfly 30 + Rocky Linux 9 work fine.